# How do I make a node link directly to its file contents in DRUPAL 6?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-nodes

I have a menu item called "Products" which when clicked displays all nodes created by the "product" content type. Every "product" node has a file attachment field with a file attached.

If I click on a "product" node, it takes me to the node as expected and I can see all the fields on the node, including the PDF field:

[image]

I want to hover over the "Products" menu link, then see the different products as a dropdown in the menu and when a product is clicked I want it to NOT go to the node, but rather open the PDF attached to the node So instead of showing e.g /product/african-decor ... it must go to  product/african_decor.pdf which is attached to the node:

[image]

Comment: The tag is Drupal 7, the heading says Drupal 6 - so what is your version? Beside of that, I don't really get what you want to do. You want to link to a field of the node? Like an anchor?

Comment: Thank you I made a mistake, fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of ways this can be achieved.

---

You can use the [Menu Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_token) module which allows you to use various fields in your menu paths. When building the token pattern you may need to create an absolute URL using the `[site-url]` token.

Also make sure the `uses tokens` checkbox is ticked.

---

This way is slightly less elegant.

Assuming you don't want to actually visit the product content type and will always download the PDF, you can overwrite the template for the `product` content type and redirect to the PDF URL.

You'd need to create

```
node--product.tpl.php
```

And replace the contents with

```
header("Location: " . $pdf_field);

// $pdf_field might be $node->field_pdf[0]['value'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implemement [hook_taxonomy_menu_path](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/taxonomy_menu/tree/taxonomy_menu.module?h=6.x-2.x#n629) with a custom module an override the base based on the nodes associated with the term. In the callback,  return the path of the attachment in the node.

- Given the fact that every term only has one node
- Given the fact that every node has only one attachment